# html5 select required if 2nd value empty

Tags: html, select, dropdown, required

`HTML5` apply `required` if `select` 2nd value empty.

**This is my example:**

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select required>
    <option value="">Select Any No</option>
    <option value="">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

For the above code `One` value empty.
I want to show required message if 2nd value also empty.

Comment: You want to disabled that option

Answer (score 0):

You can `disabled` option

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select id="number" required>
    <option value="">Select Any No</option>
    <option value="" disabled>One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code Ramesh S. Yes your are right this is also better option

Comment: Welcome Mathu K